# Live validation JQuery focusout setTimeout

Tags: validation, live, focusout

I am trying to validate data live with ajax and jquery, my ajax function returns data in every 2 seconds so i want to add some time out to focusout.

```
$("#username").focusout(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]{1,20}$/.test($(this).val()) && $(this).val().trim() !== "" && $(this).attr('availability') === 'true') {
      $(this).css("border-color", "#37ff00");
    } else {
      $(this).css("border-color", "red");
    }
  }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're experiencing?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefinedjquery.min.js:4 m.fn.extend.valvscript.js:9 (anonymous function)

this what i see in consol

Answer (score 0):

I replaced `$(this)` with `$("#username")` and it now works.